# When is typecasting a pointer allowed?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I'm studying for an exam, and one of the sample questions I've been given is the following:

"Which of the following expressions when assigned to new_val (the expression will replace **HERE**) will print **7**?" Choose all that apply:

```
float m = 7.0
int *a = (int *) &m;

int new_val = HERE;
printf("%d\n", new_val);
```

(a) *(int *) &m

(b) *a

(c) (int) m

(d) None of the above.

---

The answer is **(c)** only.

I've run the program on my own machine, and what I found agrees with the answer. However, I was wondering how someone can reason to get to this answer? More generally, I'm having trouble understanding the rules regarding casting pointers. I've read a couple of other posts on StackOverflow, which weren't too helpful to me.

I was wondering if someone could please help clarify how I can work through questions similar to this one.

Comment: (c) (or the even simpler answer (c') `m`) is the proper way to convert (or cast) a floating-point value to an integer.  Realize that this *is* a conversion: the internal representation of the `float` value 7.0 is *not* the same as the internal representation of the `int` value 7.

Comment: Answers (a) and (b), on the other hand, contrive to reinterpret the internal representation of the `float` value 7.0 as if it were an `int`, *without* doing any float-to-int conversion.  Since the `float` representation of 7.0 is typically the bit pattern `0x40e00000`, answers (a) and (b) are likely to give you something like 1088421888.

Comment: Note to OP: Although you have faithfully reproduced the question from the exam and posed it on Stack Overflow, the question is defective. The author of the exam did not fully understand the C standard, and there is no correct answer. ([My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57138524/298225) explains why.) Because of this defect, the question is not useful and should be voted down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `a = (int *)&m`, options (a) and (b) are identical. In both cases you're taking the address of `m`, casting it to `int *`, and then dereferencing it.

The reason that (a) and (b) don't work is that `&m` is a pointer to `float` (a `float *`) which is not a pointer to `int` (`int *`).

Consider two pointers, one is a pointer to a `Window`, and another is a pointer to a `Joystick`. It's pretty clear that you can't mix those up, right? You couldn't pass a pointer-to-`Window` to a function that expects a pointer-to-`Joystick`. You could cast the pointer, but that doesn't make the `Window` into a `Joystick`.

So pointer to `float` and pointer to `int` are just incompatible, and if you cast a pointer to `float` to a pointer to `int` and try to dereference it, you'll get garbage.

But (c) works because here you're taking the actual `float` value `m` and asking the compiler to convert that value into an `int` value. The compiler knows how to do this and generates the correct code.

You're probably wondering, if the compiler knows how to convert a `float` into an `int`, why can't it convert the pointer to `float` into a pointer to `int`? In fact it does; that's the purpose of the cast. But it converts the *pointer* not the *thing the pointer is pointing to*.

Comment: The conversion in `(int *) &m` may have undefined behavior per C 2018 6.3.2.3 7, and therefore the C standard permits a conforming implementation to print “7” in any of the three cases, and it also permits a conforming implementation not to print “7” in any of the three cases. In cases (a) and (b), there is also undefined behavior due to the aliasing violation.

Answer (score 1):

But using

```
int new_val = (int)m;
```

ignores everything done in this previous line with `int* a = ...`

So you are just casting the original float `m` back to an int.

**EDIT** 
try the following:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    float m = 7.1;
    int new_val = (int)m;
    printf("%d\n", new_val);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to approach this is to look at each of the multiple choice answers and work out what the meaning of the statement is. Consider the types of the variables.

But in this case, casting a `float *` to an `int *` just means you're telling the compiler "you know this memory address that holds a `float`? Access that memory as if it holds an `int`". `int`s and `float`s are not stored the same way in memory, so trying to access it in the wrong format gives a nonsense result. Casting a pointer does not convert the data which the pointer is pointing to.

In the case of option c, notice that you're not casting a pointer - you're casting a `float` to an `int`. This is a straightforward conversion.

Answer (score 1):

The question is defective. The C standard permits each of (a), (b), and (c) to print “7”, and it also permits each of them not to print “7”.

For (a), we have `int new_val = * (int *) &m;`. Here, `&m` has type `float *`, so this converts `float *` to `int *`. C 2018 6.3.2.3 7 tell us we can make this conversion: “A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type.” But it also “If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.” So, in an implementation where `float` has a stricter alignment requirement than `int`, the behavior is not defined by the C standard, so a conforming C implementation is permitted to print “7” and is permitted not to print “7”. Assuming the implementation evaluates the conversion successfully without having an alignment problem, it then applies `*`. This is covered in the next paragraph.

In (b), we have `int new_val = *a;`, where `a` has been initialized to `(int *) &m;`. As with (a), this expression converts a `float *` to `int *` and therefore falls afoul of the alignment problem above. But, again assuming the alignment problem is avoided, it then uses the pointer to access the `float` object `m` as if it were an `int`. This violates C 2018 6.5 7, which states that “An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:” and then goes on to list various options, none of which permits accessing a `float` as an `int`. Since this “shall” requirement is violated, C 2018 4 1 tells us the behavior is undefined: “If a ‘shall’ or “shall not’ requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined.” Since the C standard does not define the behavior, a conforming implementation is permitted to print “7” and is permitted not to print “7”.

In (c), we have `int new_val = (int) m;`, where `m` is a `float` with the value 7. This is a well-defined conversion, and the result is 7, so `printf("%d\n", new_val);` would normally print “7” (with a new-line character). However, the earlier problem remains: Even with this proper definition for `new_val`, the earlier declaration `int *a = (int *) &m;` performs a conversion that may cause undefined behavior. This can cause undefined behavior before we read the definition of `new_val`. Therefore, as with (a) and (b), a conforming implementation is permitted to print “7” and is permitted not to print “7”.

Comment: The question is about the difference between casting a pointer and casting a value. There's no suggestion that this is a runnable program. The definitions of `a` and `m` are just the setup for the question.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn: The question is defective. Any setup to ask about using an `int *` that originates in a `float *` must include a conversion that may have undefined behavior. So the defect is fundamental to the question; it cannot be eliminated by changing the setup. Additionally, both (a) and (b) require an aliasing violation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Look, you're right, okay? But you're right in a way that doesn't help the OP at all. The exam he's studying for isn't expecting him to detect a subtle flaw in the givens. It's asking if he knows that casting a pointer doesn't actually change the thing the pointer is pointing to while casting a value actually does change the value.